# Is there a way to shorten this jQuery script?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery, and I've coded this to fade out three thumbnails when hovering over the remaining thumbnail. It just seems messy, and I'm interested to know if there was a way to code this in a cleaner way to improve my knowledge of selectors and identifiers. Many thanks to anyone who posts!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {  
        $(".christmas-list-1,").css("opacity","1.0");
        $(".christmas-list-1").hover(
            function () {
                $(".christmas-list-2,.christmas-list-3,.christmas-list-4").stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, "fast");
            },
            function () {
                $(".christmas-list-2,.christmas-list-3,.christmas-list-4").stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, "fast");
            }
        );

        $(".christmas-list-2,").css("opacity","1.0");
        $(".christmas-list-2").hover(
            function () {
                $(".christmas-list-1,.christmas-list-3,.christmas-list-4").stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, "fast");
            },
            function () {
                $(".christmas-list-1,.christmas-list-3,.christmas-list-4").stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, "fast");
            }
        );

        $(".christmas-list-3,").css("opacity","1.0");
        $(".christmas-list-3").hover(
            function () {
                $(".christmas-list-1,.christmas-list-2,.christmas-list-4").stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, "fast");
            },
            function () {
                $(".christmas-list-1,.christmas-list-2,.christmas-list-4").stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, "fast");
            }
        );

        $(".christmas-list-4,").css("opacity","1.0");
        $(".christmas-list-4").hover(
            function () {
                $(".christmas-list-1,.christmas-list-2,.christmas-list-3").stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, "fast");
            },
            function () {
                $(".christmas-list-1,.christmas-list-2,.christmas-list-3").stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, "fast");
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you heard of a `for` loop?

Comment: Sure: the code is identical except for the index, and which element from an array of indexes should be operated on. Start there. This should likely be on [codereview](codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 6):

Don't give them separate class names, just use `.christmas-list` for all 4:

```
$(".christmas-list").css("opacity","1.0").hover(function() {
   $(this).siblings(".christmas-list").stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, "fast");
}, function() {
   $(".christmas-list").stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, "fast");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {  
    var elms = ".christmas-list-1, .christmas-list-2, .christmas-list-3, .christmas-list-4";
    $(elms).css("opacity", "1").hover(
        function () { $(elms).not($(this)).stop().animate({ opacity: .5 }, "fast"); },
        function () { $(elms).not($(this)).stop().animate({ opacity: 1  }, "fast"); }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using fadeOut http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ alongside a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling to many times to the function `$`. Try to avoid it (read the point 4 of [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-jquery-beginners-can-test-and-improve-their-code/)).

I think you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

var arrJChr = {};

    for(i=1;i<=4;i++){
        arrJChr[i] = $(".christmas-list-"+i);
    }
    var animateFun = function(idNot, nOpacity){
        for(i=1;i<=4;i++){
            if(i!=idNot){
                arrJChr[i].stop().animate(
                    { opacity: nOpacity }, 
                    "fast"
                );
            }
        }
    };

    for(i=1;i<=4;i++){
        arrJChr[i].css("opacity","1.0");
        arrJChr[i].hover(function(){
            animateFun(i,0.5);
        },function(){
            animateFun(i,1.0);
        });
    }

});
</script>
```